# Best approach to handle input fields' change in a monstrous form

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, flux

I am developing a web application, there is a form with too many input fields (about 20) where every change must be saved (I thought to use Socket.IO to notify my backend to persist all changes in real time) but handle mutiple onChange events looks so unclear. I would love to know if someone have some similar problem and how it could be done using a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach the `onChange` event to the `form` instead for event bubbling:

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  onChange: function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <form onChange={this.onChange}><input /><input /></form>;
  }
});
```

**Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/j178m3zL/**

Comment: It is definitely the cleanest way to do that, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

So you want controlled form fields it seems.

Look at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html.

I would do something like below.

https://jsbin.com/bidiwob/edit?js,output

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot, I accept David 's answer cause I think it is more elegant way to handle changes but your answer gave me a great tip to join with form's onChange event.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure want to send changes to the server on every change? this is a LOT of traffic (actually, a lot of connections) which I'm sure you don't want to have. Submit your changes `onBlur` or even `onSubmit`. This leads to a much better performance!

Comment: It‘s not a LOT of traffic if it‘s just text input fields.

Comment: right, it's probably not a lot of traffic, but a lot of (unnecessary) connections!